# Adjust CSS to resize desktop email to fit mobile client viewports

Tags: html, css, email, mobile

I am working on a designed email using SendGrid editor and am having issues figuring out how to get the email to render in mobile viewport correctly. Currently looks fine on Desktop. Using http://tedgoas.github.io/Cerberus/ as a styling foundation with a myriad of inline styles.

**Currently:** Full desktop email renders in full on mobile, getting cut off.

**Goal:** To have the designed desktop email fit entirely within the viewport on clients such as iOS Mail.app and Gmail app.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" style="height:100%; width:100%;"        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>   
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html charset=UTF-8" />
  <!-- utf-8 works for most cases -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"; content="IE=edge">
  <!-- Use the latest (edge) version of IE rendering engine -->
  <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">
  <!-- Disable auto-scale in iOS 10 Mail entirely -->
</head>
<body bgcolor="#fff" height="100%" style="margin: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;" width="100%">
</body>
</html>
<div><br />
<title>Personalized Note</title>

<style type="text/css">/* What it does: Remove spaces around the email design added by some email clients. */
        /* Beware: It can remove the padding / margin and add a background color to the compose a reply window. */
        html,
        body {
            margin: 0 auto !important;
            padding: 0 !important;
            height: 100% !important;
            width: 100% !important;
        }

        /* What it does: Stops email clients resizing small text. */
        * {
            -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        }

        /* What is does: Centers email on Android 4.4 */
        div[style*="margin: 16px 0"] {
            margin:0 !important;
        }

        /* What it does: Stops Outlook from adding extra spacing to tables. */
        table,
        td {
            mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important;
            mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;
        }

        /* What it does: Fixes webkit padding issue. Fix for Yahoo mail table alignment bug. Applies table-layout to the first 2 tables then removes for anything nested deeper. */
        table {
            border-spacing: 0 !important;
            border-collapse: collapse !important;
            table-layout: fixed !important;
            margin: 0 auto !important;
        }
        table table table {
            table-layout: auto; 
        }

        /* What it does: Uses a better rendering method when resizing images in IE. */
        img {
            -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;
        }

        /* What it does: A work-around for iOS meddling in triggered links. */
        .mobile-link--footer a,
        a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
            color:inherit !important;
            text-decoration: underline !important;
        }

        /* What it does: Prevents underlining the button text in Windows 10 */
        .button-link {
            text-decoration: none !important;
        }

        .ExternalClass {
            width: 100%;
        }
</style>
<style type="text/css">/* Media Queries */

        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) and @media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

            .email-container {
                width: 100% !important;
                margin: auto !important;
                max-width: 100% !important;
                height: auto !important;
                margin-left: auto !important;
                margin-right: auto !important;
            }

            /* What it does: Forces elements to resize to the full width of their container. Useful for resizing images beyond their max-width. */


            /* What it does: Forces table cells into full-width rows. */
            .stack-column,
            .stack-column-center {
                display: block !important;
                width: 100% !important;
                max-width: 100% !important;
                direction: ltr !important;
            }
            /* And center justify these ones. */
            .stack-column-center {
                text-align: center !important;
            }

            /* What it does: Generic utility class for centering. Useful for images, buttons, and nested tables. */
            .center-on-narrow {
                text-align: center !important;
                display: block !important;
                margin-left: auto !important;
                margin-right: auto !important;
                float: none !important;
            }
            table.center-on-narrow {
                display: inline-block !important;
            }

        }
</style>
<center style="width: 100%; background: #fff;"><!-- Visually Hidden Preheader Text : BEGIN -->
<div style="display:none;font-size:1px;line-height:1;max-height:0px;max-width:0px;opacity:0;overflow:hidden;mso-hide:all;font-family: sans-serif;">A message from %spouse1_firstname &amp; %spouse2_firstname%</div>
<!-- Visually Hidden Preheader Text : END --><!-- Email Header : BEGIN --><!-- Email Header : END --><!-- Email Body : BEGIN -->

<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="email-container" height="100%" role="presentation" style="margin: auto;max-width:100% !important;" width="650">
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
    <!-- 1 Column Text : BEGIN --><!-- Background Image with Text : END --><!-- 1 Column : BEGIN -->
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" bgcolor="#000000" style="padding-top:60px;max-width:100%;" valign="top">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" role="presentation" width="100%">
                <tbody>
                    <tr><!-- Column : BEGIN -->
                        <td background="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/vr-ac-demo/bg-Wide.jpg" class="stack-column-center" style="padding-bottom:64px;background-size:100% 100%;max-width:100%;">
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="300" role="presentation" style="padding-top: 20%;" width="530">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="text-align: center; height: 100% !important; background: #000000; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px; color: rgb(85, 85, 85); width: 100% !important;border:1px solid white;"><span contenteditable="false" tabindex="-1"><span class="sg-image" data-imagelibrary="%7B%22width%22%3A140%2C%22height%22%3A140%2C%22alignment%22%3A%22center%22%2C%22border%22%3A1%2C%22src%22%3A%22https%3A//s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/vr-ac-demo/square+crop+image.jpg%22%2C%22classes%22%3A%7B%22sg-image%22%3A1%7D%7D" data-widget="sgimage" style="float: none; display: block; text-align: center;"><img height="140" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/vr-ac-demo/square+crop+image.jpg" style="height: 140px; width: 140px; border: 1px solid transparent; margin-top: 20px; border-radius: 80px;" width="140" /></span></span>
                                    <p style="font-size:23px;font-family:arial;color:#fff;margin-top:153.9;padding-bottom:6px;">HANNAH &amp; MASON</p>

                                    <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" height="400" width="470">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="border:1px solid #ff69b4;">
                                                <p style="font-size:14px;color:#ccc;text-align:left;padding: 0 4px 20px 4px;margin-left:12px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus a orci id magna pharetra tristique et ac risus. Aenean ultricies convallis lorem. Integer vitae dignissim nisi. Nam ligula ipsum, accumsan vel mi a, ultrices tempus dolor. Curabitur mauris tortor, lacinia quis maximus nec, finibus eget velit. Nulla egestas ultricies risus. Curabitur velit nisl, semper at varius et, rutrum in ex. Ut condimentum aliquet malesuada. Curabitur rutrum interdum neque a luctus. Pellentesque sed convallis est, sed vehicula mi. Sed placerat tincidunt enim, et fringilla orci semper nec. Fusce vitae felis pharetra, consequat tellus vel, consectetur massa. Nullam convallis ex risus, at consequat justo vestibulum et. Mauris ultrices feugiat nisi, eu ornare dolor volutpat quis. Cras tincidunt lobortis justo sed accumsan.</p>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>

                                    <p style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;margin-top:20px;color:#ccc !important;width:86%;max-width:100%;margin-left:38px;text-decoration: none !important;padding-bottom:10px;line-height:1.4;">Download our App Store or Google Play and enter:<br />
                                    your email: email@​mac​.​com and code: (code)<br />
                                    or visit us at company​.​com</p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </td>
                        <!-- Column : END -->
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Column : END --><!-- Column : BEGIN --><!-- Email Body : END --><!-- Email Footer : BEGIN -->
    </tbody>
</table>
<!-- Email Footer : END --></center>
</div>
```

Comment: So, you want it to resize to fit mobile? Or you want it to be laid out totally differently? The possible solutions for your request as is are many, making this question (in its current revision) too broad.

Comment: I've worked with a colleague on the issue I am trying to explain and have made significant progress. The question is currently too broad/unclear as notes, and will update for clarity. Right now trying to get the designed email content (background image, table structure and copy) to fit iOS Mail.app.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use media query?

example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){

    .class{
         --- 
     }

}
```